# can any one pin point what is wrong with this statement?

Tags: python-3.x

```
if str(trend.name[0]) == '#'
```

I fail to see the problem it looks like a normal code to me I just wanted to check that this text is beginning with a hash "#"

Comment: what is the issue? Any error messages? Not working as intended? Please have a look at [how to ask a well received question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Things can go wrong if `trend` is `None`, `trend` has no attribute `name`, or `name` is not a non-empty string. You need to clarify your problem.

Comment: What is the error

Comment: Btw, where is a built-it string method for such task - `startswith`.

Comment: I am able to print(str(trend.name[0])) and get a single character and now I want compare if it a '#' but it gives me an invalid syntax

Comment: http://idownvotedbecau.se/noexceptiondetails/

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in starstwith string method.

```
if str(trend.name).startswith('#')
```